# UNITY ECS doesn't register new entity in runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new here and hope you may solve my little problem.

I decided to test the new ECS system in Unity and faced problem like this:

I have two entities and one system which controls both of them. When i start playmode - both entities were found by my system, but when i spawn third entity in runtime - system didn't update it.

My System:

```
public class MovementSystem : ComponentSystem
{
    public struct ComponentFilter
    {
        public Transform m_Transform;
        public MoveComponent m_MoveComponent;
    }

    protected override void OnUpdate()
    {
        var entities = GetEntities<ComponentFilter>();
        foreach (var item in entities)
        {
            Debug.Log(item.m_MoveComponent);
        }
    }
}
```

My Component:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(GameObjectEntity))
public class MoveComponent : MonoBehaviour 
{
    //do nothing. may be added to another gameObject by AddComponent 
    //if object doesn't have GameObjectEntity - creates it
    //and then system will not update it.
}
```

How can I register this new object in my system? Thank you for answers!

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, then you have not instantiated the new entity. You can do that in your MovementSystem with `EntityManager.Instantiate(Entity srcEntity)` or in another place with `World.Active.GetOrCreateManager<EntityManager>().Instantiate(Entity srcEntity)`.

Comment: I'm trying do it in your way: it doesn't help. Entity was in EntityManager, but in my System it doesn't appear (appear means that i didn't see it in entity debugger in my system, but saw it in EntityManager). And I'm trying another way: `World.Active.GetOrCreateManager<EntityManager>().AddComponent(GetComponent<GameObjectEntity>().Entity, typeof(MoveComponent));`. in this case entity appear in my system, but MovementComponent value was null (i checked this in debug.log() in system OnUpdate).

Comment: That code is used in Component which addes MovementSystem on himself if it doesn't exist (so as gameobjectentity, cuz it requiered).